# Can my app be found in another country(app store localization) with an existing name

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization, app-store, app-store-connect

Our situation is as follows: We have a Dutch app(Also one product page - Localization: Dutch) that can be downloaded by anyone in any country. The current app has a unique name and can be found and downloaded in every country.

Now we want to change the app name but we see that the name we want to use has already been taken up by some languages/regions.

What happens if people search for our new app name in a certain region/language, but the name has already been claimed in that region/country. Can our customers find our app? I am therefore curious about the behavior that arises when someone searches for our new app name that is already taken in a certain region.

Kind regards,
Sylber

---

**Another way of explanation:**

We have only provided our app with Dutch metadata (Localization: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deve6f78a8e2), and is also set as primary by default. This means that all our metadata (e.g. my app name and subtitle) of the app will be displayed in Dutch in all App Store territories. So also in the USA and UK my app name and subtitle will be shown in Dutch, because I have only localized one language and set it as primary. So now my question is if I have an app with a name that is available in the Dutch App Store, e.g. 'InvoiceApp', but which is already taken in the USA or UK, will my app be shown in the USA and UK App Store ?

Answer (score 0):

yes it will appear in search but maybe not the first app in search results.

Comment: @Sylber was my answer helpful? Did you manage to do this?